# Check marked field as required in HTML when submitting form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using Jquery `.submit()` function to submit my form using JQuery. But I've some fields marked as `required` in HTML.
How should I use the `.submit()` function to check required field before submitting the form?

‌

here is the code

```
<script>
function submit() {
    $("form").submit();
}

function signup() {
    alert("You're going to sign up");
}
</script>

<form action="JavaScript:void(0);" onsubmit="signup()" method="post">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input required="" id="email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input required="" type="password" id="password"/>
    </div>

    <a class="submit" href="JavaScript:submit();">Sign Up</a>
    <button type="submit" class="none_display"></button>
</form>
```

I need to submit my form using `a` tag because of style changing in some browsers for `button` and `input` tags.

Comment: An anchor should not be used as a button. Anchors are links to pages or sections of a page. Use a button and style it like a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's slightly strange that you have a submit() method that you inline call, that turns around and submits the form, that then executes its inline signup() method that then actually does work.  Just call the signup instead of the submit().

But for your actual question.

```
$(':input[required]').filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim() })
```

This command will find all inputs that have a required property that do not have a value.  If you find any, don't do your ajax.

The below example has refactored the logic a bit, so that the submit button is actually showing, but is styled to look like a link.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var blankRequiredFieldsExist = $(e.target).find(':input[required]').filter(function(){
    return !this.value.trim();
  }).length;
  
  if (!blankRequiredFieldsExist) {
    alert("You're going to sign up");
  }
});
```

```css
.buttonAsLink {
  border: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input required id="email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input required type="password" id="password"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="buttonAsLink">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: here, your code will work. But I won't have the default alert for HTML5 that tells the user to fill out the fields.

Comment: Nothing about this is should prevent the HTML5 alerts.  This is just checking for the existance of required fields without values.  If something is preventing the HTML5 alerts, that would be something else.

Comment: Nah. You're using `button` tag to submit the form. I need to use `a` tag because of style changing in some browsers for `button` and `input` tags. Then the style of the link seems like a submit button.

Comment: Ok, so keep what you got and use the selector in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few unnecessary things going on.

You don't need `action="JavaScript:void(0);"` on the form.

Remove `<a class="submit" href="JavaScript:submit();">Sign Up</a>`

```js
function signup() {
    alert("You're going to sign up");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="signup()">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input required="" id="email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input required="" type="password" id="password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="none_display">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not what I need. The important thing is to submit the form using `<a>`/

Comment: Semantically, you should not use `<a>` for submit as `<a>` is an anchor that links somewhere.  It *should* be a `<button>` (maybe you style it like an anchor).

Comment: Also, nowhere in your question do you state that the most important part of your requirement is to submit from the `<a>` - so it's a bit rude to downvote because someone couldn't read your mind!

Comment: I have both the link and the button tag In my code and the form is being submitted using `a` tag. of course I need to submit the form in that way! But anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make submit button and set `display: none;` for that.
then write some function in jquery to click on your submit button when user click on your anchor link

```
<form action="JavaScript:void(0);" onsubmit="signup()" method="post">
  <input type="text" required="yes" />
  <input type="submit" style="display: none;" id="mysubmit" />
  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick='$("#mysubmit").click();'>Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks